# Use flex unit as margin/padding of an element?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've two flexbox columns, but one is just empty and is used as "left margin" for the other column.

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/MKWvwo

I'd like to avoid to insert in the markup the first column but maybe define to the second column something like

```
margin-left: flex-1
```

this should just add a left-margin wide as a "flex 1" unit.

Is there a way?

*PS*

clarifying for the one that voted to close because unclear.

You have a flexbox with width `300px`, inside, you have a column with `flex: 1` and one with `flex: 2`.

The "flex unit" will be `100px` (thee are 3 flex units (1 + 2), 300/3= 100)

Comment: There is no such unit

Comment: to clarify; instead of using a margin, you're trying to use an empty flexbox item (that will never have any content in it)?

Comment: Yes, because I need to have a space on the left wide as the `flex: 1` width

Comment: here's an article detailing how `margin: auto` works with flex. https://medium.com/@samserif/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6#.hmkfm81a9 i think it's the best solution so far.

Comment: @Bchavez.gd the `margin: auto` applied to flexbox is pretty awesome, but I can't see how it can help with my problem. May you post a codepen example?

Answer (score 1):

So, your issue is to clean the DOM and avoid an artificial element.

You can use a pseudo element for this

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  }
  
.flex:before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
  
.two {
  background: blue;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  
  <div class="two"> 2</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want an empty space on the left hand side and you want the second column to be pushed to the right. If this is the case I think you can resolve your issue by adding a width(%) to your second column and add the following property to your container:

```
.flex-container{
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Get rid of the first column all together.

Comment: But I want the second column to be flexible, in the full code I have several columns, most of them have content on the first column as well, but in some of them not.

Comment: You can add %'s to both columns and it should keep the widths depending on screen size.

Comment: and if I need to add another column? I use flexbox because I'm taking advantage of its features...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the justify-content property to get the desired result. You must give a width to the remaining column that, if you want to keep it flexible should be in % units.

```
.flex{
   justify-content: flex-end;
}

.two {
    flex-basis: 66%;
}
```

See codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwzxqM

If you have more columns then you have to distribute the 100% width among them and you're done.

Comment: My example was simple for sake of having something to work on... but I may have more columns, and there I could need the flexbox. Thanks however for your solution, it could be a workaround for specific cases

Comment: Updated answer, you can use flex-basis as well

Comment: How does it change the things? I still have to calculate the percentage manually no?

Comment: You can use a margin-left on the most left column, but in any moment you should have to calculate something. I think that the easiest way could be creating clasess like .one-column, .two-columns, etc. for the container and setting the left margin of the first child to the appropiate percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox grid which is same as bootstrap grid just with Flexbox
 http://flexboxgrid.com/

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/288/)**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8 column"></div>
 </div>
```

So here `col-xs-offset-4` behave same as `margin-left`

Comment: the offsets use margins as % to push them over. i think the OP is asking for a flex solution to the margin.

Comment: Since you still can't set margin as flexbox units i think this is closest to what OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

So the criteria is that you want the left column to be a *`"flex-margin"`* at the *constant* length of one *`flex-unit`*? Take a look and see if I'm grokking* correctly.

http://codepen.io/01/pen/VewzJL

**CSS**

html,

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.4 'Source Code Pro';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: baseline;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 2 25%;
}

.two {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: blue;
  flex: 2 0 75%;
}

.two div {
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: cyan;
  min-height: 10%;
  height: 1.5em;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}
```

*That's awesome! The spellcheck accepted "grokking"!